WebRequest Timeout or not Task.WhenAny working
private Stream PostData(WebRequest request, byte[] rawByteData)
{
    Stream req = request.GetRequestStream();
    req.Write(rawByteData, 0, rawByteData.Length);

    return req;
}

public WebRequestResult RequestPostDataWebRequestResult(string url, string postData, IEnumerable<string> headers = null, string contentType = null, int timeout = 300)
{
    WebRequestResult webRequestResult = new WebRequestResult();
    try
    {
        byte[] rawByteData;
        WebRequest request = PrepareWebRequest(url, postData, headers, out rawByteData, contentType, timeout:timeout);

        Stream req = PostData(request, rawByteData);

        var response = GetResponseStreamThrow(request);

        req.Close();
        webRequestResult.Message = response.Item1;
        webRequestResult.StatusCode = response.Item2;
        webRequestResult.Status = true;
        return webRequestResult;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        webRequestResult.Message = e.ToString();
        webRequestResult.Status = false;
        if (e is WebException webException)
        {
            webRequestResult.WebExceptionStatus = webException.Status;
            if (webException.Response is HttpWebResponse response)
            {
                webRequestResult.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
            }
        }
        return webRequestResult;
    }
}
private async Task<WebResponse> TaskWithTimeout(Task<WebResponse> task, int duration)
{
    if (duration == 0)
        duration = 100 * 1000;
    var retTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(duration)).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (retTask is Task<WebResponse>) return task.Result;
    return null;
}

Even though we give 100 seconds of timeout at PrepareWebRequest, http requests throws System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond at the end of 40 minutes for some reason, instead of giving timeout error.
This does not happen every time, happens very rarely.
At GetResponseStreamThrow we called either of them, but Task.Delay and WebRequest.Timeout did not work.
WebResponse ws = await TaskWithTimeout(request.GetResponseAsync(), request.Timeout).ConfigureAwait(false);

WebResponse ws = TaskWithTimeout(Task.Run(request.GetResponse), request.Timeout).Result;

When I check the request from fiddler, I can see the handshake.
Is this really a .net bug since both WebRequest.Timeout and Task.Delay for custom timeout seems did not worked?
Also is there any better way to implement client side timeout since WebRequest.Timeout does not work for this scenario?

First of all, to clear things out, error System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection ... is not caused by your method or the way you are handling tasks in TaskWithTimeout method. If your tasks would take longer then timeout in the method, simlpy null would be returned.
If you are surprised that your task is still running, even though it exceeded timeout, it is because you do nothing to stop it. In order to stop a task that you are starting, pass CancellationToken to it.
Compare small example replicating your case:
var r = await TaskWithTimeout(MethodAsync(default));
Console.WriteLine("Got result " + r);
await Task.Delay(1000);

async Task<int?> TaskWithTimeout(Task<int> task)
{
    var retTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(300)).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (retTask is Task<int>) return task.Result;
    return null;
}

async Task<int> MethodAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(500, cancellationToken);
        Console.WriteLine("Async method ran to completion");
        return 1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Async method caught exception: " + ex.Message);
        return 0;
    }
}

You will see log Async method ran to completion, even though this method exceeded timeout.
In order to correctly stop the task, you need to use CancellationTokenSource - below is your example slightly modified to utilize it:
async Task<int?> TaskWithTimeoutWithCancel()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var retTask = await Task.WhenAny(MethodAsync(cts.Token), Task.Delay(300)).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (retTask is Task<int> task)
    {
        return task.Result;
    }

    cts.Cancel();
    return null;
}

This will correctly stop the task and will print Async method caught exception...
